# How to execute same program when it terminates?

Tags: python-2.7, jupyter-notebook

I have slow internet connection, thus my python program throws `ConnectionError` frequently. So every time I have to save the status of the code and re-execute. I am currently running my program in jupyter notebook. The `try-except` looks like -

```
try:
    page = requests.get(url, timeout = 15)
except:
    print "Connection failed, line processed:", count, line
    fstat.write(str(count) + '\n')
    fstat.close()
    fout.close()
    sys.exit(0)
```

How can I run the program again after exiting the same in jupyter notebook automatically?

Comment: what OS are you using?

Comment: @EladTabak I am using  ubuntu 16.04. It will be fine if the program will be able to run in terminal or other IDE instead of jupyter

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may use Ubuntu "UpStart" tool. See more details in [this article](http://www.alexreisner.com/code/upstart).